# Join three columns in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

So I want to join two tables. In table `nationnames` I have a column named `nation`. The second table is called `games`. In this table I have the columns `team_1` and `team_2`. I want to join them all. What I already have is this:

```
SELECT nationname FROM nation JOIN games g ON nation.nationname = g.team_1 WHERE g.typ = 'final'
```

Table nation:

```
Nation_Name     Trainer        Group
Germany         Klinsman       A
```

Table Game

```
Team_1      Team_2
Germany     Poland
```

Expectet result:

```
Nation_Name
Germany
Poland
```

Comment: please share the sample data and expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need the result on the same row  You need  join nation table two times   (using table alias)

```
    SELECT n1.nationname, n2.nationname 
    FROM games g
    JOIN nation n1 ON n1.nationname = g.team_1 
    JOIN nation n2 ON n2.nationname = g.team_2 
    WHERE g.typ = 'final'
```

But if you need  on two rows then you could use UNION

```
    SELECT nationname
    FROM games g
    JOIN nation  ON nationname = team_1 
    WHERE g.typ = 'final'
    UNION 
    SELECT nationname
    FROM games g
    JOIN nation  ON nationname = team_2 
    WHERE g.typ = 'final'
```

or

```
    SELECT nationname
    FROM games g
    JOIN nation  ON (nationname = team_1  OR nationname = team_2)
    WHERE g.typ = 'final'
```

Comment: I want to join it in one table not in two

Comment: You can't get two name from the same table  ..  .. try add  a proper data sample and the expected  result  ..as tabular text